# Ansible arista EOS

Tags: ansible

I am trying to configure a EOS switch using ansible. I have established connection between them using SSH keys, and tested the connection. I wrote a simple playbook and trying to execute it. But I am getting a **msg: unsupported parameter for module: transport**

**My playbook**

```
- hosts: EOS
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
  - arista.eos

  tasks:
  - name: Configuring VLAN 
    eos_vlan: vlanid=150 
     name=NewVLAN 
     transport={{ transport }} 
     username={{ username }} 
     password={{ password }} 
     debug=yes 
    register: vlan_cfg_output
  - debug: var=vlan_cfg_output
```

**In my inventory file**

```
[EOS]
Arista ansible_ssh_host=192.168.10.5

[EOS:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible
transport=http
username=eapi
password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of the following are you using?

- Ansible
- pyeapi
- ansible-eos

I ran a test using SSH with your playbook and hosts file and it worked fine on one of my switches.

PS: There is a mailing for questions, ansible-dev@arista.com. Also, you can raise issues here: https://github.com/arista-eosplus/ansible-eos/issues.  Both of these options are better than SO.

Comment: Hi Philip,

Thank you for your response, would you let me know which versions of Ansible, pyeapi and ansible-eos are you using. Did you mean arista.eos or Ansible-eos ? how would I check version of that ?

Answer (score 0):

While this might not completely answer your question, the arista.eos role is deprecated 
https://eos.arista.com/forum/arista-eos-was-not-found-on-httpsgalaxy-ansible-com/